# Cant create new versions of cloud code in parse on buddy

Tags: parse-platform, buddy.com

I m using parse on buddy as developement environment. my problem is that current version cloud code is 41,but when I create new version,new version is not created.can you guys point me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. The following log (note the version 6 being created successfully but then not listed):

```
D:\MyCloudCode>parse-on-buddy -c 6
Listing application versions...
Walking local public directory subtree...
Listing existing hash blobs...
11 public assets already synchronized!
Uploading cloud code...
Uploading name ? hash mapping...
Setting active version...
All done!

D:\MyCloudCode>parse-on-buddy -l
Listing application versions...
1 2 3 4 5
```

After upgrading to the **latest parse-on-buddy CLI** the upload indicated a syntax error in my .js files which was not shown with the old CLI. That being fixed the upload of new versions now works like a charm.